# Why doesn't $x^0$ equal the same thing as $x\cdot0$?

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

If $x\cdot0$ means adding zero $x$s together and $x^0$ means multiplying zero $x$s together then conceptually why aren't they both equal to the same thing?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  In the context of addition, doing nothing gives the same result as adding $0$.   In the context of multiplication, doing nothing gives the same result as multiplying by $1$.  Cf. [empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) and [empty sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum)

Comment: The identity/neutral element of addition is $0$, and the identity/neutral element of multiplication is $1$.

Comment: Because e want $x\cdot 0+x=x\cdot1,$ and we want $x^0\cdot x=x^1.$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks. So then $x^0$ means multiplying $x$ together zero times rather than multiplying zero $x$s together? And multiplying zero $x$s together actually means $x\cdot0$? Wikipedia says that empty products equal one and empty sums equal zero "by convention." Does by convention mean because the math works out well rather than some conceptual reason or does by convention mean something else?

Answer (score 2):

multiplying exponents with the same base, is the same as adding the exponents, i.e. $a^b * a^c = a^{(b+c)}$

using this consider:

$$
x^0 = x^{-1} x^1 = \frac{1}{x^1}x^1 = 1
$$

OR

$$
x^3 = x^2x \\
x^2 = x^1x \\
x^1 = x^0 x
$$

here it becomes clear the only value for $x^0$ could be 1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For $x \cdot 0$, it means by definition to "start at $0$, and move $x$ units to the right, $0$ times", which results in $x\cdot 0 = 0$, the starting place.

But for the exponent, we think $x^0$ to mean "start at $1$, and grow (in a compounding fashion) $x$ units in magnitude, $0$ times", which results in $x^ 0 = 1$, the starting place.

As comments pointed out, numbers together with the operation of addition have an additive identity $0$. And numbers together with addition and multiplication have a multiplicative identity $1$. Taking the exponent is shorthand for multiplication, hence why the starting place is 1 (the multiplicative identity).